# Spring MVC default value not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-request-parameters

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Fin_AddBankAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody JsonResponse addCoaCategory(
    @RequestParam(value="code", required=true) long code,
    @RequestParam(value="startFrom", required=true) long startFrom,
    @RequestParam(value="name", required=true, defaultValue="N/A") String name)
    {

    }
```

defaultValue="N/A" not working , As I did not provide any text in name field , it store null in database instead of "N/A"?

Answer (score 4):

What is the point of setting a default value if you really want that parameter.
if you mark it as required true(not needed as it is default) then no need of a default value.
If that parameter is not mandatory then mark it as false and give a default value.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of Spring `RequestParam.required`

> Default is true, leading to an exception thrown in case of the parameter missing in the request. Switch this to false if you prefer a null in case of the parameter missing.

From your question I figured out that you are sending parameter `name` with empty value using POST request. According to the Spring documentation you should not send `name` parameter in the request in order to use default value. Simply remove `name` field from HTML form if it is empty.

It seems that default values makes more sense for GET requests.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you don't pass empty string value
Valid Methods:
   1. Fin_AddBankAccount?name=
        O/P: name="N/A"

2. Fin_AddBankAccount?
       O/P: name="N/A"

Invalid Methods:
   Fin_AddBankAccount?name=""
this will set empty string to variable i.e. name="";

Answer (score 0):

In my project

```
@RequestParam(value="name", required=true, defaultValue="N/A") String name
```

This code correctly sets name variable as defaultvalue N/A when requestparam "name" was not provided. My guess is you are not inserting this name variable into the table properly so database is storing null instead of "N/A". Please show us or double check the data access object code. Good luck

---

Thanks @Tiarê Balbi, in fact you do not need  "required=true" because defaultValue="N/A" implicitly sets this variable as required=false anyways.