# Is it possible to set DefaultValues for Spring post?

Tags: spring, rest, post, get

i need help with my Spring Restful Service Script. Iam trying to set Default Values in a Post Body and i need to know thats possible? or not?

Its about a login who needs default values.

It works with **Get** Function with the following Code:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value= {"login/"}, 
    method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, 
    consumes = {MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE },
    produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}

public String login(@RequestParam(value= "user", defaultValue = "") String user,
                    @RequestParam(value ="password", defaultValue = "") String password)
{
    System.out.println(user+"---"+password);
```

}

But the Data are very sensible so i need to post them.

Comment: Your code should work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504401/spring-mvc-default-value-not-working

Comment: I tried this but i dont get any values. My Problem is that i dont know how to build the Http Post. SHould i set the Values in the Body or in the Url? I need to set the Values in the Body for hiding sensible values in my Body but i need to set default values if the needed values dont excist.

Comment: One way is to create ajax post: http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-post/

Comment: Thank you for your comment but i never worked with ajax... im using for my test the firefox addon RESTClient. Can someone help me with that ?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132794/firefox-add-on-restclient-how-to-input-post-parameters

Comment: Thank you everything is solved. I use the same add on and this answer was totally that what i seeked.